# Entity Framework 4.0: Entity SQL CAST Operation Not Working

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-sql

I'm trying to make a query where I cast a text column, which contains an integer as text, to an Int32. Here's the query:

```
SELECT VALUE t FROM MyEntities AS t WHERE CAST(t.TextColumn AS Edm.Int32) > 5
```

However, I get an System.Data.EntitySqlException with the following message:

> Type 'Edm.Int32' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 1, column 75.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399172.aspx), Edm.Int32 should be a valid type.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Edit:**

After some trial and error, I found that the following works:

```
SELECT VALUE t FROM MyEntities AS t WHERE CAST(t.TextColumn AS System.Int32) > 5
```

Are the examples in MSDN wrong? I feel like I'm missing something here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a query is executed with the EntityCommand, the data type is an EDM type, while if the query is executed with ObjectQuery, the data type is a CLR type.

Looks like you are executing the comman via the ObjectQuery.

Comment: I am using ObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>(). This explains the problem!