# Problem with Entity SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-sql

I am learning Entity Framework 4 from book.

And I try to make some Query with Entity SQL like this :

```
using (var context = new BAEntities())
{                
    string str = "SELECT VALUE c " +
                 "FROM BAEntities.Contacts " +
                 "AS c " +
                 "WHERE c IS NOT OF(BAModel.Customer)";

    ObjectQuery<Contact> qry = context.CreateQuery<Contact>(str);

    Console.WriteLine(qry.Count());
}
```

My query purpose is to take all Objects of Contact Type but not of Customer Type.
Where, Customer inherits from Contact

But I got the following error :

**Type 'BAModel.Customer' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas 
are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 1, 
column 64.**

But, If I do query with LINQ to Entities like this :

```
ObjectQuery<Contact> qry = context.Contacts.Where(c => !(c is Customer));
```

then program can Run correctly.

So, why in Entity SQL `BAModel.Customer` is not found, whereas I ran the code within the same project in which the model is located.

Please help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, comparing an EF query vs. your adhoc SQL isn't a good comparison. The EF query knows how to construct the SQL query as expected by the RDBMS, without chance for syntax errors.

Comment: I put the comparison just to clarify that the program can run correctly. I just confused why with Entity SQL EF couldn't found the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using an [`EntityCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684.aspx) instead of `ObjectContext.CreateQuery`.

Try this:

```
using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=MyEntities"))
{
    string str = "SELECT VALUE c " +
                 "FROM BAEntities.Contacts " +
                 "AS c " +
                 "WHERE c IS NOT OF(BAModel.Customer)";
    using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand(str, conn))
    {                    
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {                        
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["c"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826509/entity-framework-4-0-entity-sql-cast-operation-not-working) has the root of the problem:

> If your query is executed with the EntityCommand, the data type is an EDM type. If the query is executed with ObjectQuery, the data type is a CLR type.

Comment: IS NOT OF TYPE is not valid Entity SQL sintax.

Comment: @ada: What happened when you get the trace string. Confirm you're using Oracle?

Comment: Exception occured before ToTraceString(), so I didn't get the string. I use SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have found the solution. See my Answer. But, once again, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I use the wrong Namespace. 
The right fullname is BAGA.Customer not BAModel.Customer. 
The right namespace is the namespace of the classes that was generated from Model (the namespace of the classes within Model1.Designer.cs), not the namespace of the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BAModel.Customer)));
```

before running CreateQuery command.
hope this helps.